# Why can't an indexable type be passed as an array c#

Tags: c#, indexing

For example, if I have

```
class Foo{
    public float this[
        int index
    ] { get ...; set ...; }

}
....
void Bar(float[] array){...}
```

Why can't I say this?

```
 Bar(new Foo());
```

Is there some way to pass an indexable type to a method as an array of the indexed type?

Comment: No. What you're trying to do is duck typing, and c# does not support it.

Comment: It has an indexer but that doesn't make it an array.

Comment: A `float[]` will never have the same type as `Foo`--its impossible.

Comment: actually i think this is a fair question. Is there an IArray interface that something could implement so that it can be passed in place of an 'real' array? I (think) know that there isnt, but its not an impossible feature and would in fact be useful

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek It would be incomplete duck typing... where it the `Length` property? An array must be able to self-describe itself. But yes... The "duck typing" is the road that is being walked here.

Answer (score 2):

This is a huge mistake. Indexers are *not* arrays. So you can't cheat like this. Arrays have indexers I know, but their indexers has a parameter of type `int`. What if you make another indexer that has a type of `Foo`? That just doesn't make any sense.

To really make `Foo` array-like, implement some interfaces. For example, `IEnumerable<float>` and `IEnumerator<float>`.

Now in your `Bar` method, change the type of the parameter to `IEnumerable<float>`. Now, you can pass either a `Foo` object, or an array of `float`s.

For information on how to implement the `IEnumerable` interface, see

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx

You can see it in the "Examples" part.

Comment: To make it array-like he would need to implement the `IList<T>` interface. It is the only interface (together with the `IList` interface) that has an indexer. And even this wouldn't make its object castable to an array.